# EOSIO Block producer name private chain

Tags: nodeos, private-blockchain

I have built a private blockchain with EOSIO, but when I change the block producer name to my custom name it doesn't produce any blocks. 
I'm following the tutorial from the boot sequence of EOSIO.

The genesis_start.sh file is :

```
nodeos \
--genesis-json $DATADIR"/../../genesis.json" \
--signature-provider EOS8HBz89spHEdgQFJY5ERuEvpAqs5sHFRgyAudKvQDFhLSyrHD1G=KEY:5J1Pnp33fiFbeFVYskDEqQcrKLUqZ7Ss1jsouKdzeFspDGddBmX \
--plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
--plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::http_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_plugin \
--data-dir $DATADIR"/data" \
--blocks-dir $DATADIR"/blocks" \
--config-dir $DATADIR"/config" \
--producer-name **Danish** \
--http-server-address 127.0.0.1:8888 \
--p2p-listen-endpoint 127.0.0.1:4444 \
```

Comment: Why the block producer initially is eosio ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible points you should check out:

- Does your producer exists as an account on the chain
- Did you provide the producer's private/public keys pair in the signature-provider
- Did you stake >= 15% of the all EOS tokens supply. There is such a rule

Comment: yes ! i have done it again today but i couldnt be able to produce the blocks ? what is the reason no documentation for that ?

Comment: Do you have a chain to which you want to connect or you want to start a brand new chain with your producer instead of the eosio ? In case of the first scenario, checkout if you had your producer registered as such one and has votes. If you want to start a brand new network with from your producer, I don't know if this is possible. Start it with eosio and after then, connect your producer and the eosio producer will stop producing automatically, so only your producer will be active